# Sonar 4.1.1 with LDAP 1.4 Configuration

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube

I am trying to configure the Sonar with windows Active directory. I am getting the below error.

> **ERROR [rails]  Error from external users provider: Unable to retrieve details for user xxx.xxx in**

The below configurations are done in sonar.property file

```
# LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.authentication: simple
sonar.security.savePassword=true
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
ldap.url=ldap://xxxx.group.root.ad

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=OU=Users,OU=Customs,OU=Group,dc=group,dc=root,dc=ad
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=OU=Customs,OU=Group,dc=group,dc=root,dc=ad 
#ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))
ldap.group.request=((objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
```

anybody have an idea to fix the issue in sonar.

Regards
Arun.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SonarQube LDAP Authentication seems to load but won't allow login via domain user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240522/sonarqube-ldap-authentication-seems-to-load-but-wont-allow-login-via-domain-use)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with LDAP 2.1 on SonarQube 5.6 (LTS)

tl'dr

This format of ldap.user.request worked for me -

```
ldap.user.request=(uid={login})
```

If you are still reading ...

Here are some things that helped me resolving the issue

1. **sonar.log** :
   Turn the DEBUG ON and look for the actual ldap search query thats getting build and the ldap context.

```
    2017.03.14 00:35:04 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapSearch] Search: LdapSearch{baseDn=dc=test,dc=com, scope=subtree, request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0})), parameters=[harvey], attributes=[mail, cn]}
    2017.03.14 00:35:04 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url=ldap://ldap.test.com, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, java.naming.security.principal=uid=user,ou=People,dc=test,dc=com, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.referral=follow}
```

2. **ldapsearch**  :
   Run lapsearch command with same parameters from the logs (step #1)

```
    $ldapsearch -x -L -D"uid=user,ou=People,dc=test,dc=com" -w"pass" -b"ou=People,dc=test,dc=com" "(uid=harvey)" mail cn
```

3. **sonar.properties** - 
   here is my working LDAP configuration

```
    #General Configuration
    sonar.security.realm=LDAP 
    ldap.url=ldaps://ldap.test.com 
    ldap.bindDn=uid=user,ou=People,dc=test,dc=com 
    ldap.bindPassword=pass 

    #User Configuration
    ldap.user.baseDn=ou=People,dc=test,dc=com
    ldap.user.request=(uid={login})
    ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
    ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

    #Group Configuration
    ldap.group.baseDn=ou=Group,dc=test,dc=com
    ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))
```

4. **ldap.user.request & ldap.group.request**
   From the step #1 you could find out whats the correct format for query filter parameter in your case and values for bindDn (-D) and baseDn _-b)

Hope this helps =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered a similar error in Sonar 5.1.1. Here's how I solved it:

1. The *Base DN* is incorrect for use with an AD server. This worked for me:

   ```
   ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
   ```
2. Anonymous authentication to an AD server apparently doesn't work with Sonar's LDAP plugin (this assumption is [supported by the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) which specifies anonymous authentication against an AD server as "untested"). You'll need to specify a *Bind DN* (here meaning a user) for connecting with the AD server:

   ```
   ldap.bindDn=<user>@<domain>
   ldap.bindPassword=secret
   ```